# Uninitialized list size C#

Tags: c#, .net, list, generics, initialization

I have the following snippet of code:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<TIn>> splitToEvenly<TIn>(this IList<TIn> source, int splits)
{
    List<TIn[]> returnValue = new List<TIn[]>(splits);
```

But when run I get a `returnValue.Count` of `0`:

[image]

Why does this happen and how can I fix it?

*PS Just to follow the regulations:

It is expected that `returnValue` has a size of 15 because it has been assigned said value;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation, the constructor [`List(int)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dw8e0z9z(v=vs.110).aspx) will:

> Initializes a new instance of the List class that is empty and has the specified initial capacity.

The list may have a *capacity* of 15, but it is *empty* (Count = 0).

Alternatively you could use the [`List(IEnumerable)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkbw11z0(v=vs.110).aspx) constructor to initialise your list with the `source` list like so:

```
 List<TIn[]> returnValue = new List<TIn[]>(source);
```

And then it would have `Count = 23` (same as the `source`)